# How to put Ruby logic in Javascript file in Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working with my first Rails app to help students memorize English vocabulary. Right now it works like that the question word appears and button "Show answers". When user clicks answers are shown and then he can click answer which is right in his opinion.

I want to build feature "Don't show 'Show Answers' button, display answers immediately". My question is because this logic is in Javascript file so what approach I should choose?

My JavaScript file in assets folder is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

    $( "#show_answers" ).click(function() {
      $( ".answers" ).show();
      $(this).remove();
    });
});

 $(document).bind("ajaxSend", function(){
    $("#loading").css('visibility', 'visible');
 }).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
    $("#loading").css('visibility', 'hidden');
 }).bind("ajaxError", function(){
    $("#error-loading").html('<span class="label label-danger">Wystąpił błąd. Proszę odświeżyć stronę.</span>')
 });
```

I want to build seperate model called Setting with has_one association for User to keep this boolean value. So I was thinking about something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

//if 'Without Show Answer button is true in user setting'
    $("#show_answers").hide();
    $(".answers").show();
// else
    $("#show_answers").click(function() {
      $(".answers").show();
      $(this).remove();
    });
// end
});

 $(document).bind("ajaxSend", function(){
    $("#loading").css('visibility', 'visible');
 }).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
    $("#loading").css('visibility', 'hidden');
 }).bind("ajaxError", function(){
    $("#error-loading").html('<span class="label label-danger">Wystąpił błąd. Proszę odświeżyć stronę.</span>')
 });
```

game.html.haml view file:

```
-title "Nauka słówek"
.row.top-buffer
  .col-md-4.col-xs-12.col-md-offset-4.text-center
    .well.well-sm
      Wybierz prawidłowe tłumaczenie.
.row
  .col-md-6.col-xs-12.col-md-offset-3.text-center
    %p
      = link_to @first_word.pl, word_path(@first_word.id), {:class=>"word btn btn-primary btn-lg", :target => "_blank"}
    %p
      = render 'correctness_bar'
    #loading 
      = image_tag('loading.gif')
    #error-loading 
    %button.btn.btn-default.btn-lg{:type => "button", :id => 'show_answers'} Pokaż odpowiedzi
    .answers
      - @words.each do |word|
        = link_to word, check_words_path(en: "#{word}", pl: "#{@first_word.pl}", time: Time.now.to_i), {:remote => true, 'data-word' => "#{word}", :method => :get, :class=>"word btn btn-default btn-lg"}
  .col-md-6.col-xs-12.col-md-offset-3.text-center
    .row
      -if user_signed_in?
        %br/
        %span.label.label-default
          Twój wynik:
          = current_user.stat.points
          (
          = current_user.rank
          )
    - unless user_signed_in?
      .well.well-sm.top-buffer
        = link_to "Zaloguj się", new_user_session_path
        lub
        = link_to "załóż konto", new_user_registration_path
        aby śledzić swoje statystyki, które pojawią się w tabeli poniżej.
    - else
      .well.well-sm.top-buffer
        Pomóż nam rozwijać serwis
        = link_to "dodając nowe słówka.", new_word_path
  .col-md-4.col-xs-12.col-md-offset-4.text-center.top-buffer
    .form-group
      %label{:for => "sel1"} Wybierz kategorię:
      %select#select-category.form-control{:onchange => "this.options[this.selectedIndex].value  (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);"}
        %option{:value => root_path} Wszystkie
        - if user_signed_in?
          %option{:value => root_path(:category => 'Moje słówka'), :selected => params[:category] == "Moje słówka"} Moje słówka
        - categories.each do |category|
          %option{:value => root_path(:category => category.name), :selected => params[:category] == category.name}= category.name

  .col-md-6.col-xs-12.col-md-offset-3.text-center.top-buffer
    %table.table.table-bordered
      %thead
        %tr
          %th.text-center Kto?
          %th.text-center Dobre odpowiedzi
          %th.text-center Złe odpowiedzi
          %th.text-center Poprawność
      %tbody
        - if current_user
          %tr
            %td Ja
            %td{:id => 'my_good_count' }= my_stats.good_count
            %td{:id => 'my_bad_count' }= my_stats.bad_count
            %td= correctness(my_stats.good_count, my_stats.bad_count)
        %tr
          %td
            %span{"data-placement" => "top", "data-toggle" => "tooltip", :title => "Liczą się tylko odpowiedzi zarejestrowanych użytkowników."}
              Ogółem
          %td= all_good_count
          %td= all_bad_count
          %td= correctness(all_good_count, all_bad_count)
```

Comment: Can you post the view file (.html.erb) of the page in which you are using this js code?

Comment: I added game.html.haml file. You can see also how it works in real life here on [Heroku](http://angipl.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: Actually, you need to put the `js` code in the `game.html.haml` file if you want to put some rails logic in the js code. Otherwise, separate `js` file couldn't get the rails data.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript logic code is usually saved in an .js file under the assets directory. Make sure you use prototyping for this. Send in the data you want to make changes to like show and remove elements. You can also perform bind events for on click or on change inside it.